BSD Licensed code used as a part of a research project
I'm currently learning a bit more about software licenses and have realized how permissive the 3-clause BSD license is. I have a small question. If I use BSD licensed code for a computation in a research project, given the fact that the objective is to publish a paper (which do not include any source files), is there any particular requirement regarding the license given the fact that code won't be redistributed? The file I forked includes a notice from the authors requesting some of their papers to be cited, which is what I'm doing.

In terms of copyright, the output of an application is usually not related to the application itself, with the main exception being when the output contains a significant portion of the intellectual property of the application. This means that when licensing the output, you do not need to consider the license of the application.
To give a concrete example, if you are writing a document in MS Word, you do not need to consider the license of MS Word when deciding upon the terms under which to distribute your document.

is there any particular requirement regarding the license given the fact that code won't be redistributed?

No. An open-source copyright license only puts requirements on you when you distribute the code (either as source or in compiled form).

I think the implied exceptions to "is usually not related to the application itself" could be described a bit more here. As in if the software is a compiler of sorts and puts parts of itself into the output.
